# CodeIgniter Session & captcha in Windows shared hosting

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Session Problem : I unable to save my session my "ci_sessions" folder.
I want to all session save "ci_sessions" folder. We are using windows hosting database using MS Sql. Our local server working fine when i was upload live server i unable to change session path my

config.php code here

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 43200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
$config['log_threshold'] = 4;
```

.user.ini code

```
[PHP]
extension=php_gd2
open_basedir=none
error_reporting=22519
display_errors=on
error_log="D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\somthing.com\logs\php_errors\demo.somthing.com\php_error.log"
session.save_path="ci_sessions"
```

CodeIgniter Version : **3.1.11**

Live Server : **Windows shared hosting**